# Download generated pdf after ajax post

Tags: php, wordpress, fpdf

I'm working with Wordpress and I'm trying to generate a PDF in php after ajax post. I need to open my generated file in another window. I'm using this functions :

```
$('#my_button').on('click' , function(e){

e.preventDefault();
array = [];

jQuery.post( filter_params.ajaxurl, {
  'action': 'create_pdf',
  'array': array,
},
function(response){
  //$('#w').empty();
  //$('#w').append(response);
  window.open("data:application/pdf," + response);
})
.success(function(data){
});
```

});

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_create_pdf', 'create_pdf' );
```

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_create_pdf', 'create_pdf' );
function create_pdf() {

```
$array = $_POST['array'];

$pdf = new myPDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'A4', 0);
$pdf->headerTable();
$pdf->viewTable( $array);
$pdf->Output();

die();
```

}

Comment: Don't use AJAX. Just submit a form with `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 0):

to make that we should store the generated pdf temporarily  and open a new tab in the success function with the path of the generated pdf file.

```
function create_pdf() {
    
    $array = $_POST['array'];
    
    $pdf = new myPDF();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage('L', 'A4', 0);
    $pdf->headerTable();
    $pdf->viewTable( $array);
    $pdf->Output('output.pdf','F');
    
    die();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alaa for your reply. I get new tab but with empty gray content.

Comment: did you point the url of the new tab with the path of the pdf ??